Problem with instant preview in the newest version of LyX (2.4.2)
After updating LyX to v. 2.4.2, the instant preview function no longer works well when an inline formula contains MathMacros. An example:

Note that an extra horizontal space is incorrectly displayed. For comparison, this is how it looks like when the instant preview is turned off:

This does not affect the final output but is still quite bothering to someone who opted for a WYSIWYG editor like LyX... In my case, the instant preview function is mainly needed for displaying commutative diagrams and tikz figures. Much appreciation for any replies!

https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/13120
